# power off the usb device that connected pico i.MX7 Dual

Tags: android, android-things

I am new to Android Things, and I'm trying to power off the usb device that connected to the i.MX7 Dual.
After I read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#api , I find that there is no result of the VID and PID of it.

My question is that I just want to control my device via power on and power off it, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "software" solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151077/android-usb-otg-programmatically-turn-off-power-to-the-port), but seems, better way is to use MOSFET power switch, like in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/103798/132328) answer of [yo'](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/37245/yo):

> [image: MOSFET power key]

which connected to GPIO pin of Android Things board. In that case you can control your device via that GPIO pin:

```
...
gpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
gpio.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_HIGH);
// set your USB device ON
gpio.setValue(true);
...
```