# controlling hub power from linux shell

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, buildroot

I am using a buildroot image (3.12 kernel) running on my raspberry Pi with a USB LED light connected to it and I want to control on/off through the CLI.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux). However, there is no control or level file in the power folder.

Is there any kernel configuration that I have to enable to get this ?

Comment: It might not even be possible if the USB power pins are connected directly to the 5V power rails (which I think is the case for RPis).

Comment: @tangrs sadly I figured out that it is the truth :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this. I have to enable PM_SUSPEND in the kernel configuration to get the class files. But then, as mentioned in the comments, RaspberryPi has the power lines directly connected to the power rails