# How to disable a specific usb port permanently in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, usb, real-time, pci

**Is it possible to permanently disable a `usb` port in `linux`?**

I have already figured out how to disable it:

```
echo -n "0000:00:12.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci_hcd/unbind
```

**BUT after restart it is enabled.**

I have placed this script :

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
            echo -n "0000:00:12.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci_hcd/unbind
            ;;
esac
```

in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/0_disable_usb2`

But again without success. I also thought that i could disable it through `bios` but as i could see i can disable the whole `pci`.

**Is there any way of doing this?**

.. My Operating system is `Debian 7.7 64bit`. The reason i want to do this is I am trying to configure my system for `realtime` capabilities and my `usb soundcard` sharing the same `IRQ` with this port.

Comment: Did you try anything from this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16476/disabling-usb-ports-in-linux ?

Comment: @SandyElms  when i execute 'echo suspend >/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/control' I am getting 'bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
'

Comment: @gabriel Do `lsmod`. Find your driver module for USB and add the module name in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`

Comment: @muradin If the driver module for my usb is ohci_hcd and will disable it will i be able to use my other usb ports?

Comment: @gabriel No you will not! I got your point. What is output of `lsusb | cut -f 2 -d' '`

Comment: @muradin sorry for late response.. this is my output:

Comment: 001   002    003    004    005    006    007    004    006

Comment: And my usbcard is in 004

Comment: Well, what about doing this `echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/level
` and put this script in some kind of start-up script?

Comment: @muradin when i execute 'echo suspend >/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/control' I am getting 'bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65327/discussion-between-muradin-and-gabriel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should find your USB number of your device, Simply by using `lsusb`.

And in Linux everything is a file, So you can manage all of your hardware using the files.

As it describes [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux) if your kernel is > 2.6.38 you should use this keywords:

`echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"`
Then:

`echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control"`

Comment: Hey, this actually worked my usbport usb2 is disabled after reboot. And this was the question So I can mark it as solved. But what i was willing to do was to have only my usb soundcard in IRQ 16. Now The usb2 has gone but in its place usb3 appeared. Have you any idea about this?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: note this does not actually disable the *port* itself, but tells the *device driver* to disable the *device*. i currently have an issue where the kernel mistakes an empty port for a device and endlessly keeps trying to handshake it, where this wouldn't work, because there's no device driver assigned yet before the (literally impossible to complete) handshake.

Answer (score 1):

For me usb mounting is handle by a service udisk2.service if you would like to stop usb mounting then stop below service

```
root@mahasan-Inspiron-5537:~# systemctl start udisks2.service
root@mahasan-Inspiron-5537:~# systemctl disable udisks2.service
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb{x}/authorized