# After disable USB debugging android phone is not charging

Tags: android, usb

I enabled USB debugging for android studio and now I want to charge my phone but it is not charging. My phone has run out of charge completely. What can I do now?

Comment: How is this programming-related? I think you should ask on Android stackexchange.

Comment: Possibly the usb port has gone into power saving mode:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37065248/1048170

Comment: I remember something like this happen to the phone I used to test as a work daily device for my android studio projects. At first, I thought, the cable was wrong or something. Then I thought the charging port from phone was wrong. It only charges directly from wall and pc charging got f*ck up. It was an old Huawei with android 5 .

Answer (score 0):

check using another usb cable. if still it not be charging . then you have only a single option to hard reset(from boot menu). same thing happen with me.