# Is it possible to control the power in a USB port?

Tags: usb

I wonder if it's technically possible to lower/increase the output power of a USB port?

I am skeptic myself, but I ask to be sure.

Comment: Define "possible". What are the constraints? I mean you could of course change output power by attaching another power source to the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the USB spec allows for different power load states. Initially a device is supplied 100mA. Once a device can handshake with the USB controller and perform a certain request, the controller can supply a "high load" current of 500mA. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762989/is-there-software-or-code-to-alter-usb-power-output) related SO question for more details.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, yes. To get more than 500mA (USB 2.0), use a combiner cable to parallel two or more USB ports. These cables are very common as they are used by external USB hard drives to get the required current.

Answer (score -1):

It is Not Possible..Because USB already provides techniques to reduce the Power level while it connected with USB Port.There will be 3 states.

1.POWERED

2.SUSPENDED.

During suspended state it emit only less power..So it is not needed to control the output power of the USB externally..USB itself offers for Better Power Utility

Comment: _There will be 3 states._ Where's the third one?